# How do I increase size of Terminal on Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, top

I have a 48core linux box. I would like to monitor per core cpu usage. However when I use
`top` and press <kbd>1</kbd> I get an error message `"Sorry, terminal is not big enough"` 
Is there anyway I  can increase the terminal window size. Max (putty) my laptop can do is ~46 lines. Increasing window size in putty or shell's  ROWS  variable hasn't helped.

Comment: The answer depends upon which terminal emulator you are running. Do I understand correctly, that you are running PuTTY on Microsoft Windows to log into your Linux server?

Comment: Yes, I am using PuTTY on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change rows to 60 under Windows option **and**  set  "When window is resized:"  option to "Change the size of font"  to get it to work

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce your font size in putty to fit more lines. Using putty, I can see 64-cores in top on a 1920x1200 laptop monitor. You can also look into another way of looking at individual processor statistics.

Is it absolutely essential to see each CPU core's statistics? You could try `mpstat -P ALL` (installed as part of the `sysstat` package).

Comment: My screen is only 1280*800. Setting Font to 8pt didn't help, but if you select the option in the answer below, the effective font size seems < 8pt.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be using xterm, which by default uses small font. This way, I can observe 64 cores at 1080 vertical resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with VNC to 48-core server.
From the terminal run command:

```
$ echo $LINES
```

Then keep vertically re-sizing the terminal and check num lines, until the number of lines is sufficient (above 50 in my case)